# Apache Jmeter extracting __RequestVerificationToken and using it to log in

Tags: security, authentication, jmeter, automated-tests, verification

I am currently using Jmeter to automate this process however I am not able to automate the login process. I have used the following regular expression to extract the __RequestVerificationToken `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="([A-Za-z0-9+=/\-\_]+?)">`

[image]

I then proceed to request the token when attempting to log in

When running the test however I am receiving Response code of 500. When investigating the request data the token is not being pulled correctly

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember [not to use regular expressions to parse HTML data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748). It is a real headache to develop and maintain regular expressions dealing with HTML code, moreover regular expressions are very sensitive to any markup change (line break, extra space, attributes order change, etc.) so I would recommend considering switching to [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) instead. The relevant configuration will be as simple as:

- Reference name: anything meaningful, `tok` will be fine
- CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]`
- Attribute: `value`

This way you will have robust and reliable way of extracting the `__RequestVerificationToken` value.

Demo:

[image: JMeter CSS Jquery Extractor]

See [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression was missing one escaping character:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="([A-Za-z0-9+=\/\-\_]+)">
```

You can check [regex](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/15)

Answer (score 0):

You have used,

```
Reference Name: tok
```

and from Screenshot 2 it's clearly visible that

`__RequestVerificationToken=%20%7Btok%7D`

So, my guess is you have stored the value in the variable `tok` but used the variable literally.
You have to use `${tok}` to replace the value stored in the Reference.